# How to extend block with one character and return to initial block after search?

Tags: regex, search, vim

I'm trying to do a search within a visual block, (from a vimscript).

This is my code:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
a26 text tea
atext text a
atext 27 12a
a11 text 25a
aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Let say my block selection is within the '`a`' border and I want to search all numbers with 2 characters:
This is my search:
`/\%V\d\{2}\%V`

The problem with the 2nd `\%V` is that it shortened a visual block selection with 1 characters, it doesn't find the number 12 and 25 in my above example.

How can I extend the visual block selection (in a vimscript) with 1 character to the right, do the search and return to previous visual block selection?

Comment: did you try to remove the 2nd `\%V`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That works fine. Tnx

Comment: Then I added it as an answer also with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then I just write it as an answer, well this is an answer and question...:)

remove the 2nd `\%V` from your pattern would do this.

I posted first as comment, because.....

I personally have been using only single `\%V` in my work, and it worked fine. I saw this question, and checked the `:h \%V`, the help suggests using both... and it is zero-width. I don't really get why 2 `\%V`s won't work for OP's question.

so, that is to say, I know how to fix the problem, but not 100% clear, what causes the problem, I hope others could explain a bit.